# Asp.net MVC 2 Entity Framework Generic Repository method. How to update a specific column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

I have 10 tables with the same design. Each of them have an `IsActive` column.

For example:

**Category**

```
 CatID 
 CatName 
 IsActive
```

**Product**

```
PrdID
PrdName
IsActive
```

Is there a way to create a generic method to update the `IsActive` column.

```
 public void Deactivate<T>(T TEntity)
 {
     // Put the code to update 
     // IsActive
 }
```

I read about generic repository, but nothing explains how to update a specific column.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to put a `where` type restriction for your generic type on your `BaseRepository` class. Try something similar to this:

WARNING: air code ;-)

Base model:

```
public interface IDbTable
{
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class DbTable
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Your model

```
public class Category : DbTable
{
    public int CatId { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }
}

public class Product : DbTable
{
    public int PrdId { get; set; }
    public string PrdName { get; set; }
}
```

Your repository

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IDbTable
{
    void Deactivate<T>(T entity);
}

public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository
{
    public void Deactivate<T>(T entity)
    {
        entity.IsActive = false;
    }
}
```

You could go even further and extend your IDbTable to include even more generic and helpful columns. E.g.

```
public interface IDbTable
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Repo

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IDbTable
{
    T GetById(int id);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Deactivate(T entity);
}

public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseReposiotry<T>
{
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        //code to get the entity by id
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        entity.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        entity.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public void Deactivate(T entity)
    {
        entity.IsActive = false;
    }
}
```

These two articles should help you out as well:
[new Repository().DoMagic()](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2008/12/22/new-repository-lt-t-gt-domagic.aspx)
[Implementing a Simple Generic Repository with LinqToSql](http://aleris.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/implementing-a-simple-generic-repository-with-linqtosql/)

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: This is exacly what I need, thanks Charlino for the answer.
Now I want be able to create a Generic Query for the update. The only thing differents for each query is the Table Name .