# How to build a generic repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, design-patterns, oop, repository

I'm developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC with NHibernate.

Based in articles and tutorials I've found at Google, I'm using Repository for my classes.

I have 10 classes and 10 repositories. Today I figured out that 90% of mine repositories are exactly equal each other, except for the class. This is one example:

```
public class PromocaoRepository:IPromocaoRepository {
    private ISession Session;

    public PromocaoRepository() {
        this.Session = NHibernateSessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    public void Add(Promocao promocao) {
        using(ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction()) {
            this.Session.Save(promocao);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public void Edit(Promocao promocao) {
        using(ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction()) {
            this.Session.Update(promocao);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public void Remove(Promocao promocao) {
        using(ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction()) {
            this.Session.Delete(promocao);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public Promocao GetById(int id) {
        return this.Session.Get<Promocao>(id);
    }

}
```

There is a way to do a kind of generic repository witch I can use in all my classes?

If it's possible, what should I do in case I need to create a particular method for an specific class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a Generic Repository pattern with fluent nHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587965/using-a-generic-repository-pattern-with-fluent-nhibernate) - as you can see 75% of the answers are linking to an existing answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a generic repository, which you can use in the general case, and if any extra methods is needed for a particular class, add it by using inheritance. Using your example:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> :IGenericRepository<TEntity> {
    private ISession Session;

    public GenericRepository() {
        this.Session = NHibernateSessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    public void Add(TEntity instance) {
        using(ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction()) {
            this.Session.Save(instance);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    /* other methods */ 
}

public class SpecificRepository : GenericRepository<SpecificEntity>, ISpecificRepository 
{
    public void SpecialQuery()  { /* added method implementation */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to set my ISession Session as protected/public for the children repositories.

Answer (score 6):

From [**another thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587965/using-a-generic-repository-pattern-with-fluent-nhibernate):

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
  void Add(T entity);
  T Get(Guid id);
  void Remove(T entity);
}

public class Repository<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
  private readonly ISession session;

  public Repository(ISession session)
  {
    session = session;
  }

  public Type ElementType
  {
    get { return session.Query<T>().ElementType; }
  }

  public Expression Expression
  {
    get { return session.Query<T>().Expression; }
  }

  public IQueryProvider Provider
  {
    get { return session.Query<T>().Provider; } 
  }  

  public void Add(T entity)
  {
    session.Save(entity);
  }

  public T Get(Guid id)
  {
    return session.Get<T>(id);
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return this.GetEnumerator();
  }

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return session.Query<T>().GetEnumerator();
  }

  public void Remove(T entity)
  {
    session.Delete(entity);
  }   
}
```

- [**Wrapping up nHibernate in repositories**](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2008/04/04/wrapping-up-nhibernate-in-repositories.aspx)

  ---

  That being said, you should take a look at [**S#arp Architecture**](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/), which already helps you with this repetitive process using Dependency Injection.

Comment: Never thought about making the Repository inherit IQueryable<T>. Any caveats to that?

Comment: It does not inherit but implement, IQueryable is an interface. And what it basically does is just forwarding calls to session.Query<T> which already has LINQ IQueryable implementation built-in.

Comment: This answer is very enlightening! I'll study all of it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my answer to a similar question (28 votes as of right now):

[Advantage of creating a generic repository vs. specific repository for each object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230571/advantage-of-creating-a-generic-repository-vs-specific-repository-for-each-objec/1231473#1231473)

The idea is to genericize the implementation, not the interface. Instead of an outward-facing generic repository interface, create an inward-facing generic repository base class, which you use to easily implement entity-specific interfaces.

**Edit:** I should point out that generic repositories serve a *very different function* than specific repositories. Repositories are intended to encapsulate the data access mechanisms behind the entity's queries, including all of the query logic. A generic repository encapsulates the ability to create queries, but it doesn't encapsulate any *specific* query about an entity.

The point is to not make repository consumers responsible for writing their own queries. A generic repository lives at the same level of abstraction as an ORM; a specific repository lives at a level above that.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my answer to the question "[Asp.net MVC 2 Entity Framework Generic Repository Method. how to Update a specific Collumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550005/3550283#3550283)" - it should give you a good idea of what to do.

HTHs,
Charles

E.g.

Base model:

```
public interface IDbTable
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class DbTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Your model

```
public class Category : DbTable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your repository

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IDbTable
{
    void Add<T>(T entity);
    void Edit<T>(T entity);
    void Remove<T>(T entity);
    T GetById(int id);
}

public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>
{
    private ISession Session;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        this.Session = NHibernateSessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        entity.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        entity.DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;

        using(ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            this.Session.Save(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public void Edit(T entity)
    {
        entity.DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;

        using(ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            this.Session.Update(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        using(ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            this.Session.Delete(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return this.Session.Get<T>(id);
    }
}
```

Oh, and lets not forget the concrete implementation

```
public interface ICategoryRepository : IBaseRepository<Category>
{
    Category GetCategoryByName(string categoryName);
}

public CategoryRepository : BaseRepository<Category>
{
    public Category GetCategoryByName(string categoryName)
    {
        //blah
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here's another example of a generic repository](http://gist.github.com/459517)